# How to pass some Bundles as Module parameters?

Tags: scala, hdl, chisel

I'm Writing a [wishbone plumbing package](https://github.com/Martoni/WbPlumbing/blob/master/src/main/scala/wbplumbing/wbplumbing.scala) to generate Intercon Modules for my designs.
In this package named `wbplumbing` I declared two Bundle for Wishbone Master and Slave interfaces:

```
class WbMaster (val dwidth: Int,
                val awidth: Int) extends Bundle {
    val adr_o = Output(UInt(awidth.W))
// ...
    val cyc_o = Output(Bool())
    override def cloneType = (new WbMaster(dwidth, awidth)).asInstanceOf[this.type]
}

// Wishbone slave interface
class WbSlave (val dwidth: Int,
               val awidth: Int) extends Bundle {
  val adr_i = Input(UInt(awidth.W))
// ...
  val cyc_i = Input(Bool())
  override def cloneType = (new WbSlave(dwidth, awidth)).asInstanceOf[this.type]
}
```

My Intercon module take this two Bundles as parameters :

```scala
// Wishbone Intercon Pass Trought : one master, one slave
class WbInterconPT (val awbm: WbMaster,
                    val awbs: WbSlave) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val wbm = Flipped(new WbMaster(awbm.dwidth, awbm.awidth))
    val wbs = Flipped(new WbSlave(awbs.dwidth, awbs.awidth))
})
//...
}
```

The two modules I want to plug to this Intercon are in two differents package named [spi2wb](https://github.com/Martoni/spi2wb/blob/master/src/main/scala/spi2wb/spi2wb.scala) and [mdio](https://github.com/Martoni/MDIO/blob/master/src/main/scala/mdio/wbmdio.scala). Both include the wbplumbing package with bundle :

- For master :

```scala
import wbplumbing.WbMaster
```

- For slave :

```scala
import wbplumbing.WbSlave
```

Then on my "top" module I imported this :

```scala
// spi, mdio bus modules
import wbplumbing.WbInterconPT
import wbplumbing.{WbMaster, WbSlave} // <- not sure that usefull
import spi2wb.{Spi2Wb, SpiSlave}
import mdio.{MdioWb, MdioIf}
```

And instantiated it like that :

```scala
  // Wishbone parameters
  val dwidth = 16
  val awidth = 2

  // module instantiation
  val spi2Wb = Module(new Spi2Wb(dwidth, awidth))
  val wbMdio = Module(new MdioWb(mainFreq, targetFreq))
  val wbIntercon = Module(new WbInterconPT(spi2Wb.io.wbm, wbMdio.io.wbs))
```

Then I get a type error :

```
[info] Set current project to spi2ksz (in build file:/pchpch/spi2ksz/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /pchpch/spi2ksz/target/scala-2.11/classes ...
[error] /pchpch/spi2ksz/src/main/scala/spi2ksz.scala:29:47: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : spi2wb.WbMaster
[error]  required: wbplumbing.WbMaster
[error]   val wbIntercon = new WbInterconPT(spi2Wb.io.wbm, wbMdio.io.wbs)
[error]                                               ^
[error] /pchpch/spi2ksz/src/main/scala/spi2ksz.scala:29:62: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : mdio.WbSlave
[error]  required: wbplumbing.WbSlave
[error]   val wbIntercon = new WbInterconPT(spi2Wb.io.wbm, wbMdio.io.wbs)
[error]                                                              ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I'm sure the solution is stupidly simple, but can found how to do !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it was a publishLocal mistake.
At the beginning of my design I declared WbSlave and WbMaster Bundle in here respective package. Then I published it.

Then I wrote the WbPlumbing package to put in it all together. And I forget to "re"publishlocal the two modules.

Sometimes, asking the question solve the problem ;)